# When are 'near', 'near by' and 'nearby' used?

Tags: word-usage

I have read on other fora that 'nearby' is always one word, yet Bill Bryson, the famous travel writer, exclusively writes 'near by'.

Comment: There are lots of differences. _Nearby_ can function as an adjective, whereas _near_ can't. _They took shelter in a nearby gazebo_, but not **in a near gazebo_. Plus there are other uses for _near_ that _nearby_ doesn't share _near-infinite power; near-beer; He pretty near hit me;_ etc. And of course, a phrase like _near by_ doesn't occur much, because how would you tell whether to put in a space or not? The distinction is only for spelling, and doesn't really exist in the real spoken language -- like apostrophe's -- and therefore everybody makes up their own rules and considers them Correct.

Comment: @adityasrivastav If you had read carefully, you'd have seen there is no duplicate; in my question I did not include 'close by' and I specifically asked for the distinction, if there is any, between 'nearby' and 'near by'.

Comment: @JohnLawler Exactly when, if at all, to use a space between 'near' and 'by' was the essence of my question. And then "apostrophe's" as plural of apostrophy??? Dear, dear.....

Comment: Since spaces are slient, like a'postrophes, you should treat them the  same and insert them wnenever you feel they improve the tone of the discourse.

Comment: @joostkiefte Haha, what a howler... Apostrophy....

Answer (score 1):

A [Grammarly.com](http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/9500-nearby-vs-near-by/) page on the topic recommends *nearby*.  But Bill Bryson, an 800 lb. gorilla, can write pretty much anything he wants.  He may have a preference for "near by" for some odd reason.  Or it could be that it wasn't caught in proofreading.

Comment: But Bryson has written two books on proper usage, so I may safely assume him to know his onions? And why can he write pretty anything he wants?

Comment: Alas, though he's one of my favorite writers, I'm afraid that it's actually the case that those two books are full of false onions made digestible by a good writing style. They were early Bryson, and he's not attempted to do linguistics since; I'm sure he's fully aware of the problem.

Comment: When you've sold upwards of 6 million books in the US alone (Wall Street Journal 10/14/2010), you can do pretty much anything you want.  And I'll take as many false onions as he'd like to pile on my plate.

Comment: @JohnLawler Quite a sweeping, perhaps even gratuitous, statement about those false onions. Could you substantiate?

Comment: Take for instance his book _The Mother Tongue: English and How it Got that Way_, The book's been out for a long time, and has accumulated [298  reviews on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/The-Mother-Tongue-English-that-ebook/product-reviews/B00T3DR56C/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_summary?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=byRankDescending). They complain about factual errors and lack of understanding, though everybody agrees it's amusingly written. If only it were reliable.

Comment: And much of it tongue-in-cheek :)